# Send pingback to Wordpress blogs from Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, pingback

I have a Rails app in which visitors can add links to a certain model. I'm looking for some way to send a pingback to this links, the same way Wordpress does out-of-the-box.
Can't find any good reference in Stack Overflow and Google.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved to this with this gem

https://github.com/AndreasWurm/pingback

Replying my own question to help others in the future :-)